# How to use ScriptSharp generated JS with NodeJS?

Tags: script#

I tried to use a Javascript file generated by Script# in NodeJS, but it won't work due to dependencies to certain libraries that aren't available in NodeJS.

Has anyone tried using Script# generated JS files in NodeJS? How did you overcome dependency issues related to JS files it uses internally? Did you just include a bunch of them?

If not, can this feature be made available? Thanks!

Comment: The 0.8 builds have NodeJS support - include templates for creating nodejs apps and modules. The core script is also no longer dependent on browser-specific capabilities, so it can run in the nodejs environment. Script# supports using and generating modules to the commonjs pattern. Any feedback/suggestions are welcome, as are contributions in that area to flesh things out.